# How can I follow a path that i choose in XML out of Python?

Tags: python, xml, shell

this is an example.

```
< example>
 < way1>Early< /way1>
  < way1.1>Go forward< /way1.1>
  < way1.2>After Traffic Light turn left< /way1.2>

 < way2>Late< /way2>
  < way2.1>Turn after 100m left< /way2.1>
  < way2.2>After 2km you will arrive< /way2.2>

< /example>
```

How can I choose by maybe asking for one way!

if i choose "early" he should give me all the underparts of early

and if i choose "late" he should give me all underparts of late

how can i write this in python

i work with "from lxml import etree" in python

Comment: Have you read lxml documentation? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i can only give some line out

Comment: by using etree.parse() and after that print findtext

Comment: Could you please [post your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, so we can have an example?

Comment: i have really no idea how to write it down to python

Comment: Have you read the [etree documentation](https://lxml.de/api.html) and [ElementTree examples](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm#usage)?

Comment: even better, the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) has a sizeable tutorial

Comment: thank you @chillie you helped me a lot